# How to set a label text to a special character?

Tags: java, gwt, special-characters

I need to set a label to have some special characters, I'm trying:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setText("•");
label.setText("♦");
label.setText("★");
```

I'm not seeing the characters rendered though (firefox 17). The output html looks like this:

```
<div class="gwt-Label"></div>
```

Is there a different way we need to set the text to those characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do no think it is possible with Label widget. You should  be using **HTML** class which extends Label.

```
SafeHtmlBuilder builder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
builder.appendEscaped("★");
HTML widget = new HTML();
widget.setHTML(builder.toSafeHtml());
RootPanel.get().add(widget);
```

Also ensure best practice of using **SafeHtmlBuilder** class.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure your source code uses `UTF-8` encoding. If you are using Eclipse, you can set the default encoding in Windows -> Preferences.

The short version of this is: if you do absolutely everything in your GWT project and deployment using `UTF-8` encoding, then all your special characters should work as expected.

If you have lots of existing files to convert, the JDK contains a little tool to convert your files for you.

Comment: Right so eclipse prompted me to save that particular java class file as utf-8, which I did. But I guess I need to save *every* file in the project as utf-8 then?

Comment: Yes, you need to do that for this type of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html codes: `&#9733;` for star(★), `&#149;` for bullet (•) and so on.

http://www.quackit.com/html/html_special_characters.cfm

Comment: Hi, could you show a sample usage of that though - specifically how to use it with a Label?

Comment: It's just a string, that in html means star. So: `Label star = new Label("&#9733;")`, or `label.setText("&#149;")`

Comment: When I try setting it that way, the browser renders the literal string "&#149;" - it doesn't translate it into the corresponding character. Is  there anything else I need to do to the Label to get it to render the code as the character?

Comment: Opps, sorry, should have been label.setHTML("&#9733;")